# Guava in Eclipse - Range "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, collections, import, guava

I'm trying to implement Google Guava in Eclipse for the Range class. As far as I can tell I've imported the Guava library successfully, but when I try to instantiate a new range, as below, I receive the error "Range cannot be resolved to a type."

```
import com.google.*;

public class RangeTest {

    Range<Integer> testRange = Range.closed(1, 5);

}
```

I believe I'm missing either some sort of static import, or something in the method syntax.

I'm currently working through [Standford's CS106a curriculum](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111) (though Guava is for an unrelated project), so I'm using JRE 1.6 and the "Standford Eclipse" SDK. I've tried using [Dollar](https://bitbucket.org/adamldavis/dollar/wiki/Home) instead, and have been able to get it working with a static import. New to Java and programming in general.

Comment: Wildcards aren't recursive, `com.google.common.collect.*` should work.

Comment: That removed the error, thanks a bunch.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, then you probably do not need to use wildcard imports. Use the auto-complete (CTRL+Space) to complete the class name, and the explicit import will be automatically inserted. Alternatively, CTRL+Shift+O will reorganize your imports and remove unsused ones as well including new ones that you have not done yet. The benefit of using explicit imports is that you do not have to deal with any ambiguity with two classes that have the same name. Also, subclasses, such as `Map.Entry` will not be included with a wildcard import anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadocs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/overview-summary.html) contain a complete list of packages provided by Guava, and `com.google` isn't a package. As August notes the `*` isn't recursive - it means "import all classes *in this package*. Since there are no classes in `com.google` this statement does nothing.

This is one of many reasons why wildcard imports are problematic, and often discouraged (e.g. in [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.1-wildcard-imports)). If you'd written `import com.google.common.collect.Range;` you'd be off to the races.